# Need to implement delegate method in viewDidLoad in tableView with custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

Im trying to implement [BEMCheckBox](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox) and the `myCheckBox.delegate = self` needs to be se in `viewDidLoad`.
How do I do this in a `tableView`?

I have done this to my cells and tableView:
Cell file for the `tableView`:

```
import UIKit
import BEMCheckBox

protocol SizeSelectionDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didChooseSmall(cell: SizeSelectorCell)
    func didChooseLarge(cell: SizeSelectorCell)
}

    class SizeSelectorCell: UITableViewCell {



        @IBOutlet weak var smallSizeCheckBox: BEMCheckBox!
        @IBOutlet weak var largeSizeCheckBox: BEMCheckBox!
        @IBOutlet weak var smallSizePriceLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var largeSizePriceLabel: UILabel!

        weak var delegate: SizeSelectionDelegate?

          func didTap(_ checkBox: BEMCheckBox) {
            if checkBox.tag == 0 {
                delegate?.didChooseSmall(cell: self)
            }
            if checkBox.tag == 1 {
                delegate?.didChooseLarge(cell:self)
            }
        }

       }
```

`TableViewController`:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoCell") as! InfoTableViewCell
                cell.nameLabel.text = name
                cell.detailLabel.text = detail
                cell.smallPriceLabel.text = String (smallPrice)
                cell.largePriceLabel.text = String (largePrice)

            return cell

        } else {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SizeSelector") as! SizeSelectorCell
            cell.smallSizePriceLabel.text = String (smallPrice)
            cell.largeSizePriceLabel.text = String (largePrice)
            return cell
        }
  }

extension InfoTableViewController: SizeSelectionDelegate
{
    func didChooseSmall(cell: SizeSelectorCell) {
        size = "Small"
        print(size)
    }

    func didChooseLarge(cell: SizeSelectorCell) {
        size = "Large"
        print(size)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the delegate `cell.delegate = self` inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SizeSelector") as! SizeSelectorCell 
cell.delegate = self
cell.smallSizePriceLabel.text = String (smallPrice)
cell.largeSizePriceLabel.text = String (largePrice)
return cell
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately its still not working. Nothing is happening when the checkbox activates

Comment: added print statement inside **didTap** ??

Comment: Yes. Added print statement both in the `tableViewController` and the `TableViewCellFile

Comment: if you can github the project , i can check it

Comment: Thanks for offering to have a look. Unfortunately I'm not at home now, and I just have a dodggy internett over the phone. It constantly cuts out. Please let me know if you can think of anything that I should check